# Show gmail add on on selecting mails from any label

Tags: gmail-addons

I am new to write gmail add-ons. Generally Add-ons are shown only when we open 1  thread. My question is: Is there any way to show the add-on on selecting a mail from inbox or any other label, without opening the message thread?

Comment: By selecting , do you mean a check box selection ?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the add-on on checkbox selection. When user selects mail(check the checkbox) from inbox or sent or any other label, the add-on should be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gmail add-on cannot be triggered when a selection is made through checkbox. But it is a good thought, really. For some reasons , triggering is only possible when you open a thread. However it can also trigger when you switch between messages.